# C# Iterate through two arrays or List and put matches in a third array or list

Tags: c#, arrays, matching

I have two arrays

```
List<int> a
List<int> b
List<int> matches
```

And I need to put all matches in a third (match) array so that I can print that out...

I can print out both a and b like so.

```
a.Sort();
label1.Text = "";
foreach (int x in a)
    label1.Text += x + " , ";
a.Clear();
```

And so on for "b"

but how to compare the two and only take the matching integers, put them in "matching" array and print them out the same way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a linq query to get values that are in both lists...

```
List<int> a = new List<int> {1,2,3};
List<int> b = new List<int> {2,4,6,3};

var matches = a.Intersect(b);

// Create comma-separated string of matching values...  
string output = string.Join(",", matches);
```

Comment: So it would be like 
`code`
     var matches = a.Intersect(b).ToString;
     String output = string.Join(",", matches);
     label3.Text = Convert.ToString(matches);
`code`
?

Comment: Nope.  ToString isn't going to help you here.  You can loop through the matches list and create your own comma delimited string but the last line of code in my example does exactly that.  Step through the code in your debugger and look at the content of matches and output and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Jesus..... Tanks alot!!! 
My problem was that I was clearing both A and B before the compare... So much for looking at the same code for too long :-) 

Thanks alot for your help!